# how to access client side file in server side using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, iis, client

how to access client side image from an asp.net application which is published in a server? But user cannot access images due to security reasons in web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the file system on a client machine from the server. All you can do is ask your user to upload the files or to download some software which can access them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of data you want to retrieve but if it's just clipboard data you could do it using the **Clipboard** class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2thcsx4(v=vs.110).aspx